# Is this error an async/Gulp issue: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js

I'm working on a PDF tool that converts pages to base64 images. When processing a large file (over a thousand pages), however, I keep getting this error:

```sh
RangeError: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined
    at Map.set (<anonymous>)
    at AsyncHook.init (domain.js:68:15)
    at PromiseWrap.emitInitNative (internal/async_hooks.js:142:43)
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at next (/Users/grumbaut/Documents/repos/pub/packages/build/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js:31649:19)
    at promiseBody (/Users/grumbaut/Documents/repos/pub/packages/build/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js:31937:15)
    at /Users/grumbaut/Documents/repos/pub/packages/build/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js:31651:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I'm using [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to split the PDF and process the pages. The `render` method I'm calling for each page returns a promise. I wonder if the length of the number of promises is causing the above error.

I'm using this task as part of a [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) workflow. I originally had the splitting of the PDF into separate pages and the rendering as part of a single task, but I split it into two, thinking that having it as two separate tasks in a series would allow for better garbage collection. Here is my relevant code:

```js
// Split the PDF
const { numPages } = pdf;
const convert = async (num) => pdf
    .getPage(num)
    .then((page) => {
        const pageObject = {
            contents: page,
            pageNum: `${vinylPath}`,
            origin: filename,
        };
        this.pdfPages.push(pageObject);
        vinylPath += 1;
    });
let promise = Promise.resolve();
for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i += 1) {
    promise = promise.then(() => convert(i));
}
return promise.then(() => {
    cb();
});
```

```js
// call the render method for each page
const renderPagesPromise = (pageObj) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const { contents: page, origin, pageNum } = pageObj;

if (this.args.debug) {
    this.log(
        taskName,
        `Converting page ${pageNum} of ${origin} to base64.`,
    );
}
const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });
const canvasFactory = new CanvasFactory();
const canvas = canvasFactory.create(viewport.width, viewport.height);

const renderContext = {
    canvasContext: canvas.context,
    viewport,
    canvasFactory,
};

page
    .render(renderContext)
    .promise
    .then(() => {
        const contents = {
            contents: canvas.canvas.toBuffer().toString('base64'),
        };
        streamLog(taskName, `Converted page ${pageNum} of ${origin} to base64.`);
        base64.push({ ...pageObj, ...contents });
        resolve();
    });
});

const task = () => {
    const doNext = () => {
        if (!pdfPages.length) return;
        const page = pdfPages.shift();
        renderPagesPromise(page).then(doNext);
    };
    doNext();
};
```

I'm a little perplexed as to where this error is coming from. I do feel as if I have a memory leak somewhere here, perhaps, since it definitely takes up a lot of RAM and I need to increase the Node size to run it.